# How can I use regex to help scrape web data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I am trying to get URLs on a single youtube video page. youtube-dl can do this but I just need urls, so I want to learn how to do this.

it is my code to get page source: `source = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXif_9RVadI")`

I am looking for 21. line of this code: `source_line_21 = source.text.split("\n")[20]`

all urls starting with `https://r[0-9]` and including `googlevideo.com/videoplayback` and ending with `","`

I tried many of code but I always getting 0 or 1 match. But there is 15-20 matches.

```
re.match(r'https:\/\/.*googlevideo.com/videoplayback.*mimeType', source_line_21)
```

I am not good at regex, I can not get it well. Thank you for all.

Output of `print(source_line_21)[:32600]` I am searching at here. It is too long, so I paste to there: [print(source_line_21)[:32600]](https://controlc.com/da23c0fe)

Comment: Please include a [mre]. Extract a snippet of the raw HTML that contains links. Hardcode that to a variable. Then use that variable instead of `source.text` and create an example that people can copy into their environments and run to reproduce your problem.

Comment: `re.match()` only looks for the pattern at the start of the string. Use `re.search()`

Comment: @PranavHosangadi source.text is too long, I don't want to paste here. And if people want to try in their environments, I think, using my code is better and faster way to try it.
I tried `re.search()` but same again, 0 match. Thank you for comment.

Comment: _"source.text is too long"_ I know, that's why I asked for a _snippet_ of it that is relevant here.

Comment: I edited mt questioni thank you for advice. I hope it will help to me and people :)

Comment: I thought you wanted something like https://regex101.com/r/I4qd8t/2

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you, that's what I'm looking for. Actually, `[^"]` this part is my solution. It is matching and keep searching.

Comment: Great, I [added an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67413718/3832970).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you're looking to perform is slightly more involved; but can be simplified through the use of a couple tools, listed below.

I've used `urllib` in the example because my `requests` request brought back Google's "Before your continue to YouTube" cookies confirmation page, but `urllib` allowed me to bypass that rubbish.

#### Tools:

- `urllib` (or) `requests`
- **BeautifulSoup** - via the `bs4`library
- **Regex** - via the `re` library
- **JSON** - via the `json` library

#### Logic:

1. Scrape the site data
2. Parse HTML using BeautifulSoup
3. Extract the tag(s) of interest
4. Iterate through the tags and look for the JavaScript variable of interest using regex
5. Iterate through the variable's contents (using JSON) to get the URLs

#### Code:

```
# Using urllib to read site content. 
source = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXif_9RVadI").read().decode()
# Parse HTML using BeautifulSoup
soup = bs(source, features='html.parser')
# Extract all <script> tags.
scripts = soup.findAll('script')
# Build regex pattern to extract the <script> tag's content.
exp = re.compile(r'^var\sytInitialPlayerResponse\s=\s(?P<content>.*\})')

# Iterate through all scripts to find the one with video content.
for s in scripts:
    if s.string:
        m = re.match(exp, s.string)
        if m:
            data = m.groupdict().get('content')

# Extract <script> of interest's content into JSON format.
content = json.loads(data)

# Collect all URIs into a list.
urls = []
for fmt in ['formats', 'adaptiveFormats']:
    for ele in content['streamingData'][fmt]:
        urls.append(ele['url'])
```

#### Confirm URIs:

```
# Print the detected URIs:
for i, url in enumerate(urls, 1):
    print(i, url[:75])

1 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
2 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
3 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
4 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
5 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
6 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
7 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
8 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
9 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
10 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
11 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
12 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
13 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
14 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
15 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
16 https://r2---sn-8pgbpohxqp5-cimd.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=16202
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is working and I am trying to understand your code :D

Comment: This code `for ele in content['streamingData'][fmt]:` giving JSON output and there is more organized data.

Comment: My pleasure.  Glad to hear you’re finding it helpful.

Answer (score 1):

use it

```py
re.match(r'https:\/\/r[0-9][\w\-@%]*googlevideo.com/videoplayback","$', source_line_21)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution but is not actually I want.

```py
import re
from urlextract import URLExtract

source = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zXif_9RVadI")

source_line_21 = source.text.split("\n")[20]

sonuc = re.findall('https:\/\/r[0-9].*\SmimeType', source_line_21)

extractor = URLExtract()
aa = [x for x in extractor.find_urls(sonuc[0]) if "mime=audio" in x]
```

This code will give me all URLs for **mime=audio** format. I used **URLExtract** module and it is external not built-in. So, I am still looking for better way to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
re.findall(r'https://r[0-9][^"]*', text)
re.findall(r'https://r[0-9][^"]*', text, re.I)  # case insensitive
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/I4qd8t/2).

*Details*

- `https://` -  `https://` string (add `?` after `s` if you want to match `http://`, too: `https?://`)
- `r` - an `r` char
- `[0-9]` - a digit
- `[^"]*` - zero or more chars other than a `"` char.